# Why don't CSS filters work on SVG elements in Chrome?

Tags: css, svg

As far as I understand, CSS filters [should work](http://caniuse.com/#search=filter) anywhere in Chrome, but I fail to make them apply to SVG elements.

This works fine in <s>all</s> most browsers:

```
div{ filter:sepia(50%) }
```

However, this will not work in Chrome:

```
rect{ filter:sepia(50%) }
```

Here is an example:

```css
div{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
rect{
    fill:red;
}
rect:hover, div:hover{
    -webkit-filter:sepia(50%);
    -moz-filter:sepia(50%);
    filter:sepia(50%);
}
```

```html
<h2>SVG</h2>
<svg width="100" height="50">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50"/>
</svg>


<h2>DIV</h2>
<div></div>
```

...and here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LtffLagn/2/

Comment: Do you want to target the specific `rect` or would it be sufficient to target the entire svg? `svg:hover` would work as far as I know.

Comment: @timo I need to target specific SVG elements.

Comment: Then you'll need to use an SVG filter rather than a CSS filter as CSS filters cannot be applied to SVG content in Chrome yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

All credit to [@Robert Longson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson), who gave the answer: **CSS filters can not be applied to SVG elements in Chrome.** They can, however, be re-implemented as SVG filters, with some extra work. This is what I ended up with:

```css
rect{
  fill:red;
}
rect:hover{
    filter:url("#sepia");
    filter:sepia(100%);
}
```

```html
    <svg width="100" height="50">
      <defs>
        <filter id="sepia">
          <feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.30 0.30 0.30 0.0 0
                                               0.25 0.25 0.25 0.0 0
                                               0.20 0.20 0.20 0.0 0
                                               0.00 0.00 0.00 1 0'/>
        </filter>
      </defs>
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="50"/>
    </svg>
```

Firefox will now use the CSS filter, and Chrome the SVG filter. Of course, if you manage to make the SVG filter work the way you want, you could just stick with that. For me, I never managed to get exactly the effect I wanted, so I let Firefox use the better looking CSS filter.

Bug tracker for CSS filters on SVG elements in Chrome/ium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109224

Edit February 2021: CSS filters on SVG elements [will start working](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/acd9d05de2f7b07e4631238d6534d8ed4a9f8203) in Chrome 89, if everything goes according to plan!

Edit 2023: CSS filters on SVG elements work in Chrome now.

Comment: @RobertLongson Thanks, I've updated. Also, if you'd have time to make an answer out of your comments, I would be happy to make that the accepted answer!

Comment: Chrome now supports CSS filter property on SVG.

Comment: @ypnos Is that from Chrome 67? Still seems to be lacking in 66.

Comment: @leo Oh noes, I checked and it works here on version 65. Maybe it doesn't work on all platforms?

Comment: @ypnos Could be; It definitely doesn't work on Linux. If I read this bug report correctly it still isn't fixed in Chromium: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=109224 so maybe some downstream fix then

Comment: @leo Interesting as I am using Chromium 65 on Arch Linux. Oh well…

Comment: @ypnos, what does work is to set the filter on the root `<svg>` node. They still do not support setting it on inner SVG elements.

Comment: "CSS filters on SVG elements will start working in Chrome 89, if everything goes according to plan!" Did everything go according to the plan?