# This animation works in FireFox, but not in Chrome. What's wrong in the code?

Tags: css, svg

This simple animation works in FireFox, but not in Chrome.

I think he has followed all the rules, but something escapes me.

What do you think is wrong in the code for Chrome?

Thanks

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<svg version='1.1' id='project' xmlns:svg='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                                xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
                                xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>

<style type="text/css">

@keyframes gray {
  from { filter: grayscale(0);  -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);}
  to   { filter: grayscale(1);  -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);}
}

.box {
  animation: gray 3s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: gray 3s infinite linear;
}

</style>

    <g>
        <rect id="rectanguloDeFondo1" class="box" fill="green" width="120" height="245"/>
    </g>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that filters cannot be applied to elements inside the svg, but they can be replicated using the `<filter>`tag: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/svg_filters_intro.asp

A quick workaround in your case is to apply the filter to the `svg` instead of the `.box`:

```css
@keyframes gray {
  from { filter: grayscale(0);}
  to   { filter: grayscale(1);}
}

svg {
  animation: gray 3s infinite linear;
}
```

```html
<svg>
    <g>
        <rect id="rectanguloDeFondo1" class="box" fill="green" width="120" height="245"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I removed the -webkit prefix since it's fully supported by chrome: http://caniuse.com/#search=animation

Additional source: [Why don't CSS filters work on SVG elements in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32567156/why-dont-css-filters-work-on-svg-elements-in-chrome)

Comment: It's a workaround and it does the job, personally I would use svg filters